# Auto populate multiple entries to calendar base on difference of start and end date

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a VBA to find the date in a summary sheet and populate the data to a calendar for employee vacation tracking.

The data in Summary page looks like this

Month   Employee    Vacation Type   Start Date  End Date    Time
Feb Carl    Half Day PM 2/26/2015   2/26/2015
Feb Hurness Half Day PM 2/26/2015   2/26/2015
Feb Edna    Half Day AM 1/18/2016   2/26/2015

I wrote the code below to populate single line. I'd like to know how to  populate multiple entries to calendat base on difference of start and end date

Thanks in advance for any help!

Sub AddToCalendar()

```
Dim R As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startDate As Integer
Dim Employee As String
Dim Reason As String
Dim Time As String
Dim sSheet As String

'locate the info in the last row of the Summary sheet
lastRow = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
Employee = Sheets("Summary").Cells(lastRow, 2).Value
Reason = Sheets("Summary").Cells(lastRow, 3).Value
Time = Sheets("Summary").Cells(lastRow, 6).Value


'active the worksheet of relevant month
sSheet = Sheets("Summary").Cells(lastRow, 1).Value
Worksheets(sSheet).Activate

'locate the cell of specific date and enter data
startDate = Day(Sheets("Summary").Cells(lastRow, 4).Value) 
endDate = Day(Sheets("Summary").Cells(lastRow, 5).Value)

With Sheets(sSheet)
    If startDate = endDate Then
        Set R = .Range("A1:H58").Find(startDate)
         If Not R Is Nothing Then
             Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time
         End If

     Else
         Do Until startDate = endDate
             startDate = startDate + 1
             Set R = .Range("A1:H58").Find(startDate)
             If Not R Is Nothing Then
                 Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time
             End If
         Loop

     End If

 End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? There a few things I would change. (1) The line that populates `StartDate` does not specify the sheet. Change it to `startDate = Day(Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlup).row` (2) Same issue with the line starting `Cells` in the `IF` statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! It solves my problem. I've edited my post for another quesion. Could you have another look please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enter multiple lines on the summary sheet based on a date range (different start date and end date), your best bet is to first figure out how many days off the employee took. This is a fairly simple arithmetic calculation, such as:

`TotalDaysOff = EndDate - StartDate + 1`

[NOTE: We have to add 1 to the formula to get the correct number of days. For example 2/26/2015 - 2/26-2015 would equal 0, but we know it's actually 1].

Once we have the `TotalDaysOff` calculated, we can create a simple loop to populate each row, such as:

```
If TotalDaysOff = 1 then
    With Sheets(sSheet)
        Set R = .Range("A1:H58").Find(startDate)
        If Not R Is Nothing Then
            Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee     & " " & Reason & " " & Time
        End If

    End With
Else
    for i = 1 to TotalDaysOff
        With Sheets(sSheet)
            Set R = .Range("A1:H58").Find(startDate + (i - 1))
            If Not R Is Nothing Then
                Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time
            End If

        End With

    Next i
End If
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: thanks! the code somehow start adding from one day later. And what can I do to avoid the weekends?

Comment: I also wrote a do until loop and it starts from two days later. I added to my original post above. Could you take a look at it please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @qshngv RE Weekends: VBA includes a `Weekday` function. The result of `Weekday(startDate, vbMonday)` will return a 6 for Saturday and 7 for Sunday. So, use an `IF` statement: `IF(Weekday(startDate, vbMonday)) >= 6 Then...` RE Loop: The first line in your loops adds 1 to `startDate`. So, the first date that will be searched is the day AFTER `startDate`. Instead, try adding 1 at the end of the loop, after you've already searched for the actual startDate

Comment: Thanks! Another question.. as I have calender of difference months store in seperate sheets, this works for dates within one month, what if the dates expend over two months? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @qshngv Yet again, VBA's built-in functions serve our needs. The `FORMAT` function returns our date in the format that we need, based on how the sheets are named. If the month is fully written out (i.e., February): `Format(startDate, "mmmm")` returns the full month. If abbreviated (i.e., Feb): `Format(startDate, "mmm")` returns the abbreviated month. Once you've test the month, you can search for the date in the appropriate sheet. If you need help with that, post specific questions and we'll give it a try. (Side note: if my answer above helped, please mark the question as answered).

Comment: Thanks user3561813! I'm a newbie to programming and VBA, this is the first project I've been working on. After my code gets longer and longer, I found myself really lost in it... do you have some recommendations as for keep my mind and logic clear? Thanks!

Comment: You'll get the hang of it the more you program. I generally recommend (especially as a beginner) that you comment as much of your code as possible because you will begin to forget what things do. (Use the tick mark ' before a line to treat it as a comment). The other recommendation, try to break your code into smaller routines where possible, then call them from within the main code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add the code to skip weekends, but I'm a bit comfused witht the logic here. Here's what I've done, could you have a look and see what's wrong please? Thanks a lot!

```
  For i = 1 To TotalDaysOff
            With Sheets(sSheet)
                Set R = .Range("A1:H58").Find(startDate + (i - 2))
                If Not R Is Nothing Then
                    Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time

                    If skipWeekend >= 6 Then
                        Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = ""
                    Else
                        Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time
                    End If

                End If
```

Comment: I'd recommend you test for weekday before searching for the date. After all, what's the use wasting resources searching for a date when it's not relevant to our needs. Essentially: After the opening `For i = 1...` line, I'd test `IF Weekday(startDate + (i - 2), vbMonday) < 6 Then` do everything below. If it's a weekend, we don't want to do anything (presuming my logic is correct

Comment: Thanks! The thing is no matter the start date is a weekend or not, if TotaldayOff >1, there's a chance some dates will fall into weekend when populates. So the real problem is how to skip over those weekends in between start date and end date...

Comment: I got that. That's why we put the `IF` statement inside the loop. The first time through the `Loop`, it will check `startDate`; the second time through the `Loop`, it will check the day after `startDate`, etc. Did I explain that well?

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me, I posted a new question for this. Could you have a look please? Thanks!http://stackoverflow.com/q/28753719/4602281