# VBA find empty cells between non-blanks & skip weekends when auto populate to calendar

Tags: excel

I'm trying to build a staff vacation tracker to auto populate the data from one summary sheet to a calendar built in Excel.

I have a few questions about it.

Firsy, when populating to calendar, I want the code to skip over weekends.

Second, if multiple employee takes vacation on the same date. I want to be able to find the next blank row under the date.

The calendar looks like this:

[image: calendar]

There're other dates below the date so I coudn't use the rows.count to find the last empty row.

The following code is part of and if statement to populate multiple days.

Other part of my code could be found in this post

[Auto populate multiple entries to calendar base on difference of start and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28749052/4602281)

I'm trying to resolve the two quesions listed above.

I'm a beginner in programming. There're too many layers and I coudn't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
 For i = 1 To TotalDaysOff

        If Weekday(startDate + (i - 2), vbMonday) < 6 Then

            With Sheets(sSheet)
                Set R = .Range("A1:H58").Find(startDate + (i - 2))
                If Not R Is Nothing Then

                    If IsEmpty(R.row + 1) Then
                        Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 1, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time

                    Else
                        Sheets(sSheet).Cells(R.row + 2, R.Column).Value = Employee & " " & Reason & " " & Time

                    End If


                 End If

            End With

         Else
         End If

   Next i

End If
```

Comment: I know the Rows.count function for finding the last row. The thing with my question is that I'm trying to find the next empty cell between rows with text. Hope I've explained my situation...

Comment: Is there any chance you could post a screenshot of the calendar so that we can better understand your structure?

Comment: Hi, I posted the calendar. Sorry about the inconvinience.

Comment: For my understanding, are the numerical values in the calendar sheet [representing the days] entered as dates that are formatted to only show the day, or did you just enter the day number into the cell?

Comment: Hi, the date was entered using a formula, adjusted by each month                                              =IF(AND(YEAR(JanSun1+10)=CalendarYear,MONTH(JanSun1+10)=1),JanSun1+10, "")

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at my post again? I still couldn't figure out how to skip weekends and roll to the next row if a record exist. thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the answer.. but i think the below can help

[Count number of blank cells in row between last cell and next non-blank cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988648/count-number-of-blank-cells-in-row-between-last-cell-and-next-non-blank-cell)

If you can count and if the count returns Zero then you may need to find another cell to fll the data..
If the count is greater than Zero, then you can try locating the cell by IF statements, as mentioned in the same question.